# Prevent a user from deploy pods into a master

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to disallow pod schedule to a SchedulingDisabled master?

If a pod uses this toleration, it can be always scheduled:

```
tolerations:
- operator: Exists
```

The master node has these taints:

```
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                    node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      true
```

```
$ kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE                              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
deploy-b976f9795-rc2t5   1/1     Running   0          5m51s   192.168.0.15    master01   <none>           <none>
```

```
$ kubectl get node -o wide
NAME                              STATUS                     ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master01    Ready,SchedulingDisabled   master   38h    v1.15.3   10.12.0.51    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-62-generic   docker://18.9.9
node01   Ready                      node     38h    v1.15.3   10.12.0.62    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-62-generic   docker://18.9.9
```

Comment: can you share output of `kubectl get nodes -o wide`?

Comment: @prometherion I've added the output

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you are using [Taints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) 
`Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` 
 which should not allow Pods to be assigned to this node. However, you  are using one of the special cases:

> An empty key with operator Exists matches all keys, values and effects
>   which means 
>   this will tolerate everything

```
tolerations:
- operator: "Exists"
```

> An empty effect matches all effects with key key.

```
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Exists"
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is to use [Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity), [Node isolation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-isolation-restriction) or just use [Node Name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodename).